# In greeter, how avoid username login with smartcard

Tags: 18.04, login-screen, pam

I using a pam smartcard module, the user is in the smartcard. In ubuntu 18.04 before start pam.d configs the system ask for a username. Its possible disable this username question and keep all login configs in pam.d files?